# Ruling on shortening both sides and back of the hair more than the middle

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, sunni, hair

is it prohibited for Muslim men to shorten hair from both sides and back than middle?

Comment: Have you done any research at all yet? i.e read an hadith/fatwa or something?